# Determine if a class member's type was defined as a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given a generic class:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Declared as:

```
var someVar = new Foo<string>();
```

Is there any way to tell if the type of `Data` is defined as a generic T and not string?

I know you can check if the type of `Data` is a string, but I want to determine if a member is defined by a generic parameter.

I am not trying to determine if `Data` is a string. I am trying to check if `Data` was defined by T. I do not think this is possible.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It is not possible to instantiate a `Foo<T>` without supplying a type parameter, so `someVar` will never be a `Foo<T>`. To test if it's a `Foo<string>`, use `someVar is Foo<string>`.

Comment: Updated question with some clarification. I don't need to know anything about someVar. I'm trying to check if someVar.Foo is defined by T

Comment: Yes, but you first have to get the generic type definition for the class. So do `someVar.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();`, then inspect the properties. One of them will have a type that has `IsGenericTypeParameter` as `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go through the generic type definition, in which the properties using the generic type parameters will still be open:

```
void Main()
{
    Test(typeof(Foo<string>), "Data");
    Test(typeof(Foo<string>), "Bar");
}

public void Test(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType)
        type = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericTypeParameter)
        Console.WriteLine("<generic> " + pi);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("<not generic> " + pi);
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
<generic> T Data
<not generic> System.String Bar
```

Comment: Note that if you don't go to the generic type definition I don't believe there is any way to distinguish this on the properties as the type is then closed, and thus "resolved" to the final types.